# spyOn question regarding function that return promise

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jasmine, spy

This is a rather general question about spyOn when writing unit tests with functions that return promises in a Vue component.

The way I write test is the following:

```
// Basically this function gets data from a service and sets some data in the component.
function getSomething() {
ServiceX.getSomething().then(response => 
this.x = response.x
)
}
```

the test:

```
describe('test', () => {
beforeEach() => {
vm = shallowMount(VueComponent)
spyOn(serviceX, 'getSomething).and.returnValue(promsie.resolve(data));
}

it('should set X', () =>{
vm.getSomething()
expect(vm.X).toBe(X);
})
}
```

The issue is, when I do the test this way, the variable X is not set yet, but if I do the "it" statement async and await for the getSomething() method it works.

I wonder if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your original method returns a promise, and your spy is also returning a promise (even an already resolved) you should use the `then` or the `async` `await` as you commented in the question.

So, the other way of doing is:

```
it('should set X', (done) => {
    vm.getSomething().then(() => {
        expect(vm.X).toBe(X);
        done();
    });
})
```

Using the `done` parameter from jasmine to notify this unit test is asynchronous and will complete when this callback is called.

Answer (score 0):

i know it's a little bit too late and you probably already found a solution, but in case you didn't i think that the solution i will propose will work for you. You can use the combination of fakeAsync and tick to test your asynchronous function, bellow is my solution.

```
describe('test', () => {
             ...
             it('should set X', fakeAsync(() =>{
               vm.getSomething();
               tick();
               expect(vm.X).toBe(X);
             }));
             ...
}
```